# How to cast/convert a BufferedImage into an Image?

Tags: java, image, awt, itext, bufferedimage

I would like to convert a `BufferedImage` to an `java.awt.Image`.

My source-image is tif so I use JAI to read it as `PlanarImage`:

> PlanarImage source = JAI.create("fileload", IMG_DIR + tagImgName);

I then save it as an objects attribute as a `BufferedImage`

> tagImg = source.getAsBufferedImage();

For .pdf-Export (via iText) I need it as `java.awt.Image`

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[java.awt.image.BufferedImage](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) is already a subclass of [java.awt.Image](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html), so you shouldn't need any casting or converting. You can use the BufferedImage in place of a Image.

You can do directly this:

```
Image tagImg = source.getAsBufferedImage();
// use tagImg with iText library here
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you mean [`java.awt.image.BufferedImage`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html), it already subclasses `java.awt.image.Image` - so you shouldn't need to do anything.